# Dynamically display fetched data in input field using Laravel and Vue Js

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have a form to take request for accessories of mobile phones. so basically here i have four tables -- accessories, accessories_request, accessories_request_details, accessories_vendor.

Accessories is having vendor_id, barcode, description.
Accessories request is having user_id, store_id, request_date, status.
Accessories details is having accessories_request_id, vendor_id, barcode, description, quantity, status.
Accessories vendor is having just name . example apple, samsung.

[image]

This is my script

```
<script>
           var app = new Vue({
           el: '#app',
           mounted: function() {
               this.addLine();
           },

           data() {
               return {
                   stores: {!! $stores !!},
                   accessory_vendors: {!! $accessory_vendors !!},
                   form: {
                       vendor_id: '',
                       store_id: '',
                       barcode: '',
                       lines: []
                   },

               }  
           },
           methods: {
               addLine: function() {
                   this.form.lines.push({
                       vendor_id: '',
                       description: '',
                       qty: '',
                       barcode: ''
                   })
               },
               removeLine: function(index) {
                   this.form.lines.splice(index, 1);
               },
               formSubmit: function(e) {
                   e.preventDefault();
                   let currentObj = this;
                   axios.post('/accessory/store',{
                       data: this.form,
                   })
                   .then(response => {
                       $(location).attr('href', '/accessory')
                   })
                   .catch(function (error) {
                       alert('Error');
                   });
               },
               getAccessory(barcode) {
                   axios.get("/getdetails/?barcode=" + barcode).then(res => {
                       //this.form.lines = res.data
                       data= res.data;
                       console.log(data)
                   });
               }
           }
       })
       
       </script>
```

This is my page code -

```
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="content" id="app">
        <!-- Lock Forms -->
        <!-- <h2 class="content-heading">Add User</h2> -->
        <!-- Register Forms -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <!-- Bootstrap Register -->
                <div class="block block-themed">
                    <div class="block-header bg-gd-dusk">
                        <h3 class="block-title">Add Accessory</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block-content">
                        @include('errors.error')
                        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" @submit="formSubmit">  
                            @csrf
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <label>Select Store</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="store_id" v-model="form.store_id" required>
                                       <option v-for="store in stores" :key="store.id" v-bind:value="store.id">@{{store.channel_id}} - @{{store.street_name}}</option>
                                    </select>   
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <table class="table table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Barcode</th>
                                        <th>Vendor</th>
                                        <th>Description</th>
                                        <th>QTY</th>
                                        <th>Actions</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr v-for="(line,k) in form.lines">
                                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="barcode" v-model="line.barcode" @change="getAccessory(line.barcode)" required></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select v-model="line.vendor_id" class="form-control" name="vendor_id" required>
                                                <option v-bind:value="vendor.id":key="vendor.id" v-for="vendor in accessory_vendors" >@{{vendor.name}}</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td><input type="text" v-model="line.description"class="form-control" value="" required></td>
                                        <td><input type="number" v-model="line.qty"class="form-control" required></td>
                                        <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" @click="removeLine(k)" v-if="form.lines.length != 1" required>Remove</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="3">
                                        <button type="button" @click="addLine()" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Add Row</button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right">Create</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END Bootstrap Register -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

This is my controller code --

```
public function getaccessory() 
    {
        //return 'test';
        $barcode = request('barcode');
        $getaccessory = DB::table('accessories')
        ->where('barcode', $barcode)
        ->select('id', 'vendor_id', 'description')
        ->get();
        return response()->json($getaccessory); 
    }
```

I need help regarding one thing ---

1. getAccessory function is fetching data from the database whenever we type anything in barcode input field, it is displaying data in console. I want if the results match from the barcode textbox to database accessories table, it should get binded with vendor and description and should display to user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getaccessory function, we just need to pass index of particular textboxes then only it is going to display the data.

```
 getAccessory(barcode, index) {
    this.form.lines[index].description = '';
    this.form.lines[index].vendor_id = '';
    axios.get("/getdetails/?barcode=" + barcode).then(res => {
             data= res.data;
             console.log(data)
             this.form.lines[index].description = res.data[0].description;
             this.form.lines[index].vendor_id = res.data[0].vendor_id;
    });
}
```

and while calling -- it should be

`<input type="text" class="form-control" name="barcode" v-model="line.barcode" @change="getAccessory(line.barcode, k)" required>`